# How to print git tag info selectively?

Tags: git

I need a way to print git tag info selectively.

Firstly I choose git for-each-ref to print all tag info:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/tags/
```

It's output looks like:

```
proj1_v1.0.0
    content
proj1_v1.0.1
    content
proj2_v1.0.0
    content
```

It's right, but I want to print the message which only contains "proj1".

After I find the solution in git dev guide(https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref)

> Used as %(if)…​%(then)…​%(end) or %(if)…​%(then)…​%(else)…​%(end). If there is an atom with value or string literal after the %(if) then everything after the %(then) is printed, else if the %(else) atom is used, then everything after %(else) is printed. We ignore space when evaluating the string before %(then), this is useful when we use the %(HEAD) atom which prints either "*" or " " and we want to apply the if condition only on the HEAD ref. Append ":equals=" or ":notequals=" to compare the value between the %(if:…​) and %(then) atoms with the given string.

I change my script to

```
 git for-each-ref  --format="%(if) %(refname:equals=proj1*)%(refname:short) %(end)" refs/tags/
```

But it raise error:

```
fatal: unrecognized %(refname:equals=hi) argument: equals=hi
```

Do I have a misleading on this sequence?

> Append `:equals=<string>` or `:notequals=<string>` to compare the value between the `%(if:…​)` and `%(then)` atoms with the given string

Comment: `git --version` ?

Comment: git version 2.17.1

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `%(if:equals)`:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(if:equals=proj1)%(refname:short)%(then)%(refname:short)%(end)" refs/tags/
```

PS. `equals` doesn't accept `*` for wildcards.
PPS. Also don't forget `%(then)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(if) %(refname)%(refname:short) %(end)" refs/tags/proj2*
```

is works.